# What are the surnames and given names of these fictional people of the Three Kingdoms?

Tags: names, history, surnames

[金環三結,董荼那,阿會喃,忙牙長](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fictional_people_of_the_Three_Kingdoms#Chapter_87)

What are their surnames and given names. For example, is 董 the surname of 董荼那?

Answer (score 1):

In 《三國演義》 孟獲 (Meng Huo) was  described as 蠻王 (king of the Barbarian). The fictional characters in his army were supposed to be barbarians. Their names were supposed to be transliteration from barbarian's language. There's no point of trying to find out their surnames.

The funny thing about transliterated name is --  the meaning of the Chinese characters in it are irrelevant. For example, the name '約翰遜' (Johnson) has nothing to do with  約 (approximately) 翰 (writing brush) or 遜 (inferior).

*約翰遜's last name is certainly not 約; 約翰遜 is a last name*

Comment: Thanks! If 孟获 is the king of the Barbarian, is 孟 his surname? After all, his brothers are named 孟节，孟优。 Does he not speak the same language as 金环三结?

Comment: @Zuriel  孟获 was from China, you can Google him. In fictional stories, even alien speak our language